# Can i wrap Provider from context with provider from redux? The <AuthContext.Provider is not from redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

Can I wrap a Provider from context with a Provider from redux? The <AuthContext.Provider> in the example below is not from redux.

```
  return (
<Provider store={store}>
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user,setUser }}>
    <OfflineNotice />
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} theme={navigationTheme} >
      { user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator /> }
    </NavigationContainer>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
</Provider>
```

);

Comment: But you would be creating two sources of truth. Is that really desirable?

Comment: That's fine. I don't see any issues here, I've been working on this pattern, but make sure to use them correctly as now you have 2 sources of truth like EVeras said